# HTTP Stripe Request Not Going Through [Swift]

Tags: php, ios, swift, filezilla

I am currently linking my IOS app with the backend to process Stripe payments. I am using FileZilla to host the files, and cSpan to host the server. Here is my swift code:

```
 let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, errorD -> Void in
        if errorD == nil {
            print("got response")

            do {
                let jsonResult: NSDictionary? = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary



                let jsonComp = jsonResult?.value(forKey: "completion") as! String
                print(jsonComp)
            } catch {
                print(errorD?.localizedDescription)
                // ERROR OCCURS HERE 
            }



            //let jsonResult: Any! = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)
           // print(jsonResult)

            } else {
            print("error")
        }
    }) task.resume()
```

And here is a screenshot of my FileZilla directory:

[image: Screenshot]

(I just realized that the picture doesn't actually show the file 'token.php' in the Payments directory, but it is there.)

As you can see, I am properly going into the correct directory to get to the file, and performing the right methods to get complete the HTTP request. What is strange, however, is that it will always cause an error after the 'catch', but it will display nil when I try to print the localized description of the error. Here is the php code inside of token.php

```
<?php

require_once('stripe-php/init.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_eRFc0VoIi7mo7zBuArrznB5a");

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form

$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$amount = $_POST['amount'];

$type = $_POST['type'];

$name = $_POST['name'];

// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card

try {

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(

"amount" => $amount,

"currency" => "usd",

"source" => $token,)

);



//email the purcahse and code info to your email

mail("willcohen2000@gmail.com","Purchase done","amount: $amount , type: $type, name: $name");

// create a json output with completion variable, (this will be read from the ios app as response)

$json = array(

'completion' => 'done'

);

echo json_encode($json);

} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {

// The card has been declined

$errorMessage = $e->getMessage();

$json = array(

'completion' => $getMessage()

);

echo json_encode($json);

}

?>
```

As it may be a bit evident, I am relatively inexperienced at backend work, so any explanation or point in the correct direction will be highly appreciated. Thanks.